# How to print all lines that matches a particular string?

Tags: linux, awk, printing, grep, find

I am intending to print all the lines with their line numbers along with its location within a specific directory which matches a particular string

**Example**..

```
/home/some_dir/file.txt -(LineNo) -(printing_thatlineitself)
```

I currently have 2 commands with me but both have some shortcomings

```
find /home/some_dir -type f -exec grep -Hn "Text To Find" {} \;
```

This above find command seems to work accurately but the issue is that it works quite slow

```
find /home/some_dir -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Hn -C2 "Text To Find"
```

This command works comparatively quite faster but it provides inaccurate results. It even prints those lines where my inputted string is not present at all

Can someone provide a solution that works accurately and is fast as well?
PS / its fine if the solution doesn't use the find command to achieve this .it just has to be something I can directly run in CLI

Comment: `-C2` is present in second command but not first... to make first one run faster, use `{} +`... if your content is ASCII, use `LC_ALL=C grep` to get even faster result.. another suggest is to use [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep) instead of find+grep

Comment: `grep` can search recursively on its own, try `grep -IHnr "my regex" /home/some_dir/`. If you want to find a simple text you can use `-F` too which indicates you're looking for fixed string not regex.

Comment: `grep -IHnr "Text to find" .` is the robust and fast way to do this job.-

Comment: It is probably not actually true that the `xargs` solution is faster, though it may start printing results sooner under some conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments , grep can be used to do this very efficiently

```
grep -IHnr "Text to find" .
```

`-I : Process a binary file as if it did not contain matching  data (to exclude binary files)`

`-H : Print the filename for each match`

`-n : Display the matched lines and their line numbers`

`-r : Recursively search subdirectories listed`

`"Text to find" : Search string`

`. : Directory for search (current directory)`

Answer (score 0):

I would not squeeze everything into one command. It is simpler to write a small shell script which combines several utilities. For example,

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh   
IFS='
'
for i in `find . -type f`
do
    awk '
    /Text To Find/ {
        print FILENAME, NR
    }' "$i"
done
$ chmod +x script.sh
$ ./script.sh 
./script.sh 7
```

Comment: Copy/paste that script into http://shellcheck.net and/or see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082 for some issues.

Comment: sh != bash, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5725402/1534218

Comment: /bin/sh could be (and probably is these days) aliased to /bin/bash on any given system. In any case, shellcheck takes your shell into consideration and the issues I'm referring to apply in any bourne-like shell.